# DDL generation and general persistence.xml settings (OpenJPA)

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, openejb, apache-tomee

**Summary**

I'm trying to run a Java web application JPA 2.0 example. The [example application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqst.html) was written to run in `Glassfish`, using `EclipseLink` as JPA provider.
I would like to convert it to run in `TomEE` with `OpenJPA` as the JPA provider, but I can't any detailed tutorials for getting up and running with `OpenJPA`.

**Problem**

I'm having trouble converting `persistence.xml` to work with `OpenJPA` instead of `EclipseLink`. More specifically, the given `persistence.xml` doesn't specify:

- `Entity` classes. Are these necessary?
- The desired JPA provider. Will the container default to something?
- The JDBC driver. How do I specify an "in-memory" DB (just for initial testing purposes)?

Also:

- How are the DDL generation properties expressed in OpenJPA? I wasn't able to find them the [OpenJPA User Guide](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html).

**Details**

Below is the EclipseLink `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="order" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="both" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have the following `Entity` classes:

- `order.entity.LineItem`
- `order.entity.LineItemKey`
- `order.entity.Order`
- `order.entity.Part`
- `order.entity.PartKey`
- `order.entity.Vendor`
- `order.entity.VendorPart`

**Question**

- Does anyone know what the equivalent persistence.xml would look like for OpenJPA?
- Alternatively, if anyone could point me to an OpenJPA tutorial that covers these issues that would be just as good

Comment: Have you spent any time reading the OpenJPA user manual?

Comment: If you have a specific link, that would be **swell**. I'm going through these now: http://openjpa.apache.org/samples.html

Comment: I haven't been able to find any persistence.xml properties for DDL generation, in here: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add the `openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings` property as shown below OpenJPA will auto-create all your tables, all your primary keys and all foreign keys exactly to match your objects

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
```

Alternatively, you can use EclipseLink in TomEE by just adding the EclipseLink jars to `<CATALINA_HOME>/lib/`

refer here for [Common PersistenceProvider properties](http://openejb.apache.org/common-persistenceprovider-properties.html)

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded EclipseLink, but am not sure which .jar files I need. I found the following jar files in EclipseLink/jlib/jpa/ : ´eclipselink-jpa-modelgen_2.3.2.v20111125-r10461.jar´, ´javax.persistence_1.0.0.jar´, ´javax.persistence_2.0.3.v201010191057.jar´. Are these the only files I need to copy into lib/?

Comment: This is a new question I guess, I'll create another one. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You tell what to create table but i must know that how can i prevent openjpa trying to create tables?Something like:<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="false"/>

Comment: Simply removing the `openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings` property should do it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Foreign key constraints

The next line does not create foreign keys:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" 
          value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
```

Only creates schema and deletes content of a database.

But if you want create foreign keys, use the following lines:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" 
          value="buildSchema(foreignKeys=true,schemaAction='dropDB,add')"/>
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" 
          value="native(foreignKeys=true)" />
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults" 
          value="ForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict, JoinForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict"/>
```

#### See generated SQL

In another way, if you want to see the SQL output:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" 
          value="DefaultLevel=TRACE,SQL=TRACE" />
```

<sub>**NOTE**: In order to see the generated output in the TomEE console, you need to change the log level in the file `loggin.properties` with `openjpa.level = FINEST`</sub>

---

See more in http://openjpa.apache.org/faq.html